# What is Key Name?? while creating RunInstanceRequest for AMI (Amazon machine Image)

Tags: amazon-ec2

if I set Key Name as 'Default' it throws error that 'Key pair Default does not exist as well from where I can get Key Name, I am using a public AMI. and also have tool ElasticFox..is there any place in this tool where I can found Key Name???

Any Idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your browser open AWS console. Go to EC2 tab. You should see in the right part under My Resources the keypairs (if you do not have one you can create - the UI is pretty intuitive).
The name of the keypair is the key name you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

keyname refers to ssh keypairs. You can create a new keypair on Elasticfox and use it to launch your instance.